# How can I make this React Component written better to be more efficient?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, components

How can I make this React Component written better to be more efficient? I feel like I'm repeating code in `onIncrement` and it could be refactored much better. The `maxValue` prop is optional

**ButtonStepper.tsx:**

```js
// TypeScript Type: Props
interface IProps {
  onChange: (value: number) => void;
  minValue?: number;
  maxValue?: number;
  stepValue?: number;
}

// Component: Button (Stepper)
const ButtonStepper = ({ onChange, minValue, maxValue, stepValue }: IProps): JSX.Element => {
  // React Hooks: State
  const [value, setValue] = useState<number>(0);

  // React Hooks: Lifecycle Methods
  useEffect(() => {
    onChange(value);
  }, [onChange, value]);

  // On Increment
  const onIncrement = (): void => {
    if (maxValue && maxValue <= value) {
      if (stepValue) {
        setValue((prevState) => prevState + stepValue);
      }
      else {
        setValue((prevState) => prevState + 1);
      }
    }
    else {
      if (stepValue) {
        setValue((prevState) => prevState + stepValue);
      }
      else {
        setValue((prevState) => prevState + 1);
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Well, if I'm not mistaken your outer `if... else...` blocks are doing exactly the same thing. What's the point of having the condition `maxValue && maxValue <= value`?

Comment: Questions prefaced with wanting "better" or "more efficient" tend to garner opinionated responses, and as such are considered off-topic on SO. If this code is running and working then perhaps it'd be better suited for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If there is an actual issue then please clarify and ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to add the default values in your props destructuring.

```
// Component: Button (Stepper)
const ButtonStepper = ({ onChange, minValue, maxValue = Number.MAX_VALUE, stepValue = 1 }: IProps): JSX.Element => {
  // React Hooks: State
  const [value, setValue] = useState<number>(0);

  // React Hooks: Lifecycle Methods
  useEffect(() => {
    onChange(value);
  }, [onChange, value]);

  // On Increment
  const onIncrement = (): void => {
    if (maxValue > value + stepValue) {
       setValue(value + stepValue);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Is there any difference from writing `setValue(value + stepValue);` to `setValue((prevState) => prevState + stepValue);`?

Comment: Also thank you for introducing me to `Number.MAX_VALUE` and `Number.MIN_VALUE`. I didn't know that existed.

Comment: Edit: `Number.MIN_VALUE` should be replaced with `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`. `console.log(Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY  < -10) // true`  whereas `console.log(Number.MIN_VALUE  < -10) // false`